# Is setting up a fake repository for a fake web service proxy class a good idea?

Tags: web-services, unit-testing, proxy, repository

When setting up a **web service**, I can have it use a **repository** class to fetch the data to send back to clients.  If I need to unit test the logic being done by the service, I could inject in it a reference to a fake repository which returns a handful of hard-coded data objects to avoid calls to a database.

On the **client side**, however, let's say I have an MVC-based web application that calls this web service via a service proxy.  **If I want to unit test the logic in the MVC app and feed it data that is representative of what the service would return, how can I fake the proxy reference?**  My thoughts are thus, though I don't feel 100% confident about this and wonder if I might be missing a simpler solution:

I can set up a proxy interface (let's call it **IProxy**) and then set up two concrete implementations of it (let's say, **Proxy** and **FakeProxy**) and inject the one appropriate to the situation being executed (FakeProxy when running unit tests, and Proxy for the actual production application). In order to generate some sample data for the unit tests without making the actual service calls, **should I then implement a fake repository (maybe the same one being used in the server scenario above) in the Fake Proxy?**  I'm unsure of how to best set up a fake proxy class to assist with the testing of my client side code.

**Update:**

I agree with the answers posted so far, but I'd already considered their points, so let me provide some sample C# code that illustrates why I'm asking this.  If I leave a fake repository out of my proxy design, my **fake proxy** might look something like this very simple contrived example:

```
public class FakeCustomerProxy : ICustomerProxy
{
    private List<Customer> Customers;

    public FakeProxy()
    {
        Customers = new List<Customer>();

        Customers.Add(new Customer { Id = 1, Name = "Smith, John" });
        Customers.Add(new Customer { Id = 2, Name = "Johnson, Al" });
        Customers.Add(new Customer { Id = 3, Name = "Thomas, William" });
    }

    public Customer GetById(int customerId)
    {
        return Customers.Where(c => c.Id == customerId).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

The **GetById()** method, instead of making a call to a web service to derive the desired customer information, simply returns it from the hardcoded customer list imbedded in this class.  This really starts to resemble what I might set up for a fake repository (I may even have very similar-looking code set up server-side to assist with testing the service logic), so I was curious if I should consider placing these hardcoded customer references into a dedicated fake repository class to be used in multiple places.  **Am I maybe thinking through the design of this Fake Proxy completely wrong?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, setting up fake repository for fake web service proxy does not seem to be a good idea for unit tests.

Actually, just one fake (proxy or repository) shoud be enough generally.

I'd suggest you to look at mocking frameworks (e.g. [Moq](https://code.google.com/p/moq/) or [Rhino Mock](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/oss/rhino-mocks)).
Using mocks, you won't even need to have `FakeProxy` implementation. In each test you can easily setup separate mocked implementation of `IProxy` which will act exactly as you need: return predefined data, raise exceptions, verify passed parameters, etc.

So, you won't need to implement 1 or 2 fake classes for testing.

**UPDATE:**
So, I see 2 options here:

1. To have non-reusable simple test data, which is specific for each particular test. You might need to setup something like mini-repository (about 1-3 items)  per each test or group of tests;
2. To have large enough reusable fake repository, which is common for both server-side & client side code. Most likely you will need to support some additional harness to use this fake repository in client-side tests and in server-side tests. E.g. you need `FakeProxy` additionaly to test client-side code.

You should consider those options and choose what is more suitable in your case.

In my opinion, option 1 is suitable for unit tests, but option 2 might be useful for integration tests.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - please see my update above for extra context on what I'm asking.  Perhaps my thinking on the fake proxy class is backwards?

Comment: Please see my updated answer, hope it helps you to make a good decision for your case :).

Comment: I think I see what you're saying.  If I'm following you, I shouldn't need to create a fake repository _and_ a fake proxy at the same time, because I'm either going to be unit testing my client-side code, in which case I just need to feed it dummy data (via the fake repository), or I'll be unit testing my service proxy, which should be completely outside the scope of this web app.  If I need to fake a call to the proxy when unit testing my client app, a mocking framework is what I should be considering for that point.  Hopefully, I'm not misstating anything here.  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

No, you should not repeat your implementation of repository-proxy connection in tests. Sooner or later there will be some business logic between proxy facade and repository, and you will have to implement it twice - on server side, and on client side, in FakeProxy.

So your mock instance of FakeProxy should just return raw data from calls.

On the other hand, you could import real Proxy class in client tests, and mock repository for testing, but this would be an integration test, not a unit test, and would involve usage of server-side code in client tests, which is not always possible.